# input is not storing in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

In my Laravel project form input isn't storing in database though I have added everything necessary. this is the store function in controller

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
    ]);

    $vehicle = new Vehicle();
    $vehicle->name = $request->name;
    $vehicle->description = $request->description;
    $vehicle->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $vehicle->sub_category_id = $request->sub_category_id;
    $vehicle->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
    //$vehicle->tax_id = $request->tax_id??0;
    $vehicle->color = $request->color;
    $vehicle->four_hour = $request->four_hour;
    $vehicle->four_hour_price = $request->four_hour_price;
    $vehicle->four_hour_discount = $request->four_hour_discount;
    $vehicle->eight_hour = $request->eight_hour??'no';
    $vehicle->eight_hour_price = $request->eight_hour_price;
    $vehicle->eight_hour_discount = $request->eight_hour_discount;
    $vehicle->full_day = $request->full_day;
    $vehicle->full_day_price = $request->full_day_price;
    $vehicle->full_day_discount = $request->full_day_discount;
    $vehicle->stock = $request->stock??0;
    $vehicle->available_from = $request->available_from;
    $vehicle->available_to = $request->available_to;
    $vehicle->vehicle_class = $request->vehicle_class;
    $vehicle->model = $request->model;
    $vehicle->body = $request->body;
    $vehicle->seat = $request->seat;
    $vehicle->actual_msrp = $request->actual_msrp;
    $vehicle->horse_power = $request->horse_power;
    $vehicle->torque = $request->torque;
    $vehicle->transmission = $request->transmission;
    $vehicle->suspension = $request->suspension;
    $vehicle->clearance = $request->clearance;
    $vehicle->differential = $request->differential;
    $vehicle->gear_ratio = $request->gear_ratio;
    $vehicle->save();
    return back()->withSuccess('Vehicle added successfully');
    return $request;
}
```

Among the variables all but body, vehicle_class, seat, actual_msrp are storing finely.

this is the database table after inputting some instances.

[image]

Here body, vehicle_class, seat, actual_msrp columns are null though i have input them.
here is the name of these fields in the table and it matches with the variables in controller file.

```
<tbody id="morerow0">
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Model</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="model"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Color</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="color"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Class</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="vehicle_class"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Body</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="body"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Seat</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="seat"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="attrrow01">
                                            <td>Actual MSRP</td>
                                            <td><input required class="form-control" type="text" name="actual_msrp"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
```

What went wrong here? how can I fix this?

Here is the vehicle model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
//

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\VehicleCategory','category_id');
}

public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\VehicleCategory','category_id');
}

public function brand(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\VehicleBrand','brand_id');
}
}
```

Comment: can you share the vehicle model ?

Comment: @Vidal I added the vehicle model

Comment: Are you submitting your form through javascript?

Comment: yes I used JavaScript. @bertdida

Comment: I suspect the issue is on your js, will you be able to include your js code submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the validate you request the name only. But in the form i don't see it.
I would recommend yo to put after `$vehicle->save();`...

```
var_dump($vehicle);// to see what error does it has//

die();
```

Comment: those variables are null as die dump shows. what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is '$guarded' (or '$fillable') property in your model "Vehicle".

```
$guarded = ['id'];
```

Also, You don't need to set each value from your form manually.

```
  $vehicle = new Vehicle($request->except('eight_hour', 'stock'));
  $vehicle->fill([
     'eight_hour' => $request->eight_hour ?? 'no',
     'stock' => $request->stock ?? 0,
  ]);
  $vehicle->save();
```

Comment: I added the vehicle model. Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: where should I put $guarded = ['id'];in model?